# Autostart Mac application programmatically

Tags: macos, autostart

We have a cross platform application. The application has a feature to autostart it once the user logs in. How to do this in mac? from within the application. Manually adding it Login Items works but I am looking for how to do it using an API or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a GUI app adding it as a login item is the best way to go.  [Apple's dev note on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002134-SW2) lists 3 ways to do this: with the Shared File Lists API, via [Apple Events](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/LoginItemsAE/index.html), or with the CFPreferences API.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I stumbled upon it today and followed your advice. A helpful advice for readers from >2012: The CFPreferences API approach is deprecated now. ("In previous versions of OS X, it is possible to add login items by sending an Apple event, by using the CFPreferences API, and by manually editing a property list file. These approaches are deprecated.")

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a launchd property list file and place it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchAgents`, depending if you want the change system-wide or only for the current user.

[This guide from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html) will help you accomplish that task.